# Call function inside static function of the class

Tags: php, oop

In laravel framework i often use  -  Model::find($id)->orderedBy(param);

I would like to know how to achieve such expression. I began with this:

```
 Class Test
 {
    static public function write()
    {
       echo "text no 1";

       function second()
       {
          echo "text no 2";
       }
     }
 }
```

now i when i do

```
Test::write();
```

i get "text no 1"

what i want is to do:

```
Test::write()->second();
```

and get " text no 2"

Unfortunately my way doesn't work.

Is it possible ?

Excuse me for bad language - still learning.

Comment: Any function that wants to let the caller continue chaining (in your example, `write`) must `return $this` (or some other object, less commonly). Since `write` is `static` and does not have a `$this`, it should somehow produce an object and return that (this is what `find` has to do in the Laravel example).

Comment: Nesting functions like this is considered bad practise, because `second()` isn't part of the class, but is registered in the global scope; and subsequent calls to write() will complain that it is already defined

Answer (score 0):

`Model::find($id)->orderedBy(param)` just means that static method `find` returns object, who's method `orderBy` is then executed.

Example:

```
Class Test1
{
    public function say_hello()
    {
        echo 'Hello!';
    }
}

Class Test2
{
    static public function write()
    {
        $obj = new Test1();
        return $obj;
    }
}

Test2::write()->say_hello();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Test
 {
    static public function write()
    {
      echo "text no 1";
      return new Test();
    }

    function second()
    {
          echo "text no 2";
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Logically it is not possible, you cannot call `second()` until you have called `Test::write()` and you can call it later because afterward the PHP will redeclare the function. So you need to change your approach.

If you return an object from the `write()` method it is possible.

```
Class Test
 {
    static public function write()
    {
       echo "text no 1";
       return new Test(); //return the Test Object
    }

    function second()
    {
          echo "text no 2";
    }

 }
```

Now you can call `Test::write()->second();`

Comment: Am I missing something... or have you just taken whole example from other answer?